# what does 'slot' mean in scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

Recent days, I was learning the source of scrapy so that I can deal with my graduate work.But I had faced some problems that I cannot deal with about scrapy.Because of the wall in my Internet, I cannot search happily with my problem.Also my English is poor and I'm not sure I can understand it even i get sth. on the Internet.So i want ask for help.As all the core module in scrapy has a class named 'slot', what does it mean?And what does it functions in the Scrapy flow?

Comment: Is my answer helpful??

Comment: thanks, sorry to accept it lately because of the GFW.

Comment: No problem :) what is GFW?

Comment: Just a fire wall but this one is much more powerful than others. You can learn more about on wiki.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slot in scrapy means the **Slot engine**

For more information, you can review the base code [here](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/core/engine.py).

When you start the telnet engine on your machine engine, you can see/manage this code

```
telnet localhost 6023
>>> est()
Execution engine status

time()-engine.start_time                        : 8.62972998619
engine.has_capacity()                           : False
len(engine.downloader.active)                   : 16
engine.scraper.is_idle()                        : False
engine.spider.name                              : followall
engine.spider_is_idle(engine.spider)            : False
engine.slot.closing                             : False
len(engine.slot.inprogress)                     : 16
len(engine.slot.scheduler.dqs or [])            : 0
len(engine.slot.scheduler.mqs)                  : 92
len(engine.scraper.slot.queue)                  : 0
len(engine.scraper.slot.active)                 : 0
engine.scraper.slot.active_size                 : 0
engine.scraper.slot.itemproc_size               : 0
engine.scraper.slot.needs_backout()             : False
```

Slots can be used to define the progress initiation and/or scheduler processing.